# eclipse oxygen のコードの折りたたみ

Tags: eclipse

visual studio の#regionように
eclipse oxygen でコードを折りたたむ方法はございますか？

coffee-bytes プラグインにて実現可能という情報がありましたので
インストールしてみたのですが 私の環境 eclipse oxygenでは動作しないようでした。
※ [ウインドウ-設定-java-エディター-折りたたみ] のダイアログにプラグインのコントロールが表示されません

coffee-bytes参考ページ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp

またコードを折りたたむ方法以外にコードを見やすくする方法はございますか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ヘルプ - 新規ソフトウェアのインストール からインストールすることができました。
https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding/raw/master/com.cb.platsupp.site

coffee-bytesでコードの任意の場所で折りたたむことができるようになりました。

使い方はこちらを参考にしました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940199/how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding

Answer (score 0):

試してませんが、coffee-bytesプラグインのフォークも駄目ですかね？

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding